# Define a function that takes 2 arguments and randomly returns one in R

Tags: r

This is the question and what I have thought of. I am new. Please help.

Define a function that takes 2 arguments and randomly returns one.

```
return_one <- function(w){
  v <- w + 2 | v <- w + 4
  return (v)
}

return_one(3)
```

If you have any suggestions please leave them.

Comment: Change it to `v <- w + sample(c(2, 4), 1)`?

Comment: `function(w)` looks like a function that takes one argument, `w`. A function that takes 2 arguments looks like `function(w, x)`, with the two arguments `w` and `x`. Without giving too much away, I'd start with `return_one <- function(w, x) {if(...) {...} else{...}}` and leave it to you to fill in the `...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular problem, it seems like all you need to do is:

```
return_one <- function(w){
  v <- w + sample(c(2, 4), 1)
  return (v)
}
```

Here's what we get when we execute the function 10 times with "3" as the input.

```
## set.seed is just being used for reproducibility
set.seed(42)
replicate(10, return_one(3))
#  [1] 7 7 5 7 7 7 7 5 7 7
```

---

You can make it a bit more generalized by using something like `switch` along with `sample`. Here's a function that randomly samples one of three functions:

```
return_one_alt <- function(w){
  ran_fun <- sample(3, 1)
  switch(ran_fun,
      "1" = w + 2,
      "2" = w + 7,
      "3" = w - 10)
}
```

As before, let's test it on 10 replications:

```
set.seed(42)
replicate(10, return_one_alt(3))
#  [1] -7 -7  5 -7 10 10 -7  5 10 -7
```

---

As noted in the comments, your function only has one argument, "w". A function that has two arguments would look like:

```
fun_with_two <- function(x, y) { ... do some stuff here ... }
```

"x" and "y" would be your two arguments.

From there, you need to decide whether you're really looking at having something happen randomly (in which case `sample` is probably going to be of help) or whether you want something to happen conditionally (in which case `if (...) { ... do something ... } else { ... do something else ... }` or `switch` would be of help).

Comment: The description said "a function that takes 2 arguments" but you seem to only have one argument.

Comment: Also, as this seems almost certainly to be a homework question, might be worth giving OP hints rather than a solution.

Comment: @MrFlick, looking at what they were attempting, I'm not sure that they are using their terminology correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I saw what they were doing, but the description to me sounded like it was copy/pasted from a homework assignment and it was their attempt that was wrong rather than the other way around. But if the intention was to have a single argument, this makes total sense. I suppose the question just isn't very clear.

Comment: @GregorThomas, No problem. I CW'd it in case you want to edit in any other hints.